# Android listview scroll

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I want to move my listview one item automatically after 5 seconds.
I have 10 items means 10 strings in my adapter i want to make that after 5 seconds listview automatically scroll and move to next item.

Comment: As always: what did you try? Show us the code! :-)

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? Can you show some of your code / research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without other informations is hard to help you. Anyways you could use this and add a timer that call method every 5 seconds. You should also modify the index of smoothScrollToPosition to return the right item index:

```
private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
     myListView.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
    }
});
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try to do something like this. Use a timer that call this method and be sure to put index to 0 at the end of the scroll or whenever you want:

```
 int index=0;//field


 private void scrollMyListviewOnebyOne() {
     myListView.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
             listView.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
               if(index < myListAdapter.getCount()) index ++;


    }
});
}
```

Comment: I have done this but it is directly going to last position. I want to go to 7th position if i am at 6th...

Comment: see the last example I post.